# Problems in animating graphs and its extrema

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, manipulate

I tested to animate 2D graph and its extrema for simple case using Mathematica.

```
localmin[k_] := Solve[g[k]'[x] == 0 && g[k]''[x] > 0, x]; 
localmax[k_] := Solve[g[k]'[x] == 0 && g[k]''[x] < 0, x];
Manipulate[
 Plot[g[k][x], {x, -15, 15}, PlotRange -> 10, 
  Epilog -> {{PointSize[Medium], Red, 
  Point[{x, g[k][x]} /. localmin[k]]}, {PointSize[Medium], Blue, 
  Point[{x, g[k][x]} /. localmax[k]]}}], {k, 1, 4} ]
```

But, when I evaluated and moved parameter `k` or played the animation, the figure just frozen and doesn't work properly. I think it is caused by trivial mistake. I'm newbie and so can't find where trobule comes. Could you fix this?

Comment: Can you give a [complete minimal example](http://sscce.org/)?  I.e. what is the definition of `g`?

Comment: A wild guess: do you need `k` to be an integer?  If so, use `{k,1,4,1}` instead of `{k,1,4}`. You'll need to show `g` for us to say more

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: It might help to restrict the domain of `x` in `Solve`s, e.g., `localmin[k_]  := Solve[g[k]'[x] == 0 && g[k]''[x] > 0 && -15 <= x <= 15, x];`

Comment: Oh! Sorry, g[k_] is defined as `g[k_] := Function[x, (x^2 - k)(x^2 - 1)]`

Answer (score 1):

One problem with the code is that you invoke `Solve` every time you move the slider in the manipulate.  But your function is easy enough to solve for the extrema as it is:

```
g[k_] := Function[x, (x^2 - k) (x^2 - 1)]
Solve[g[k]'[x] == 0 && g[k]''[x] > 0, x]

(* {{x -> ConditionalExpression[0, k < -1]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-(Sqrt[1 + k]/Sqrt[2]), k > -1]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[1 + k]/Sqrt[2], k > -1]}} *)
```

There is a problem that for some values of `k`, the local minimum is undefined.  Since you are interested in the case where `k` is between 1 and 4, let's just define the `localmin` and `localmax` functions with this in mind.  Also, we define them with the `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) so that `Solve` is not invoked every time you move the slider.

```
localmin[k_] = Solve[g[k]'[x] == 0 && g[k]''[x] > 0 && k > -1, x];
localmax[k_] = Solve[g[k]'[x] == 0 && g[k]''[x] < 0 && k > -1, x];
Manipulate[
  Plot[g[k][x], {x, -15, 15}, PlotRange -> 10, 
   Epilog -> {{PointSize[Medium], Red, 
      Point[{x, g[k][x]} /. localmin[k]]}, {PointSize[Medium], Blue, 
      Point[{x, g[k][x]} /. localmax[k]]}}], {k, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just another way (for this quartic polynomial)  :

```
g[x_, k_] := (x^2 - k) (x^2 - 1);
gd[x_, k_] := D[g[u, k], u] /. u -> x
gdd[x_, k_] := D[gd[u, k], u] /. u -> x
sol[k_] := {PointSize[0.02], 
   RGBColor[Boole[gdd[x, k] > 0], Boole[gdd[x, k] < 0], 0], 
   Point[{x, g[x, k]}]} /. Solve[gd[x, k] == 0, x, Reals]
Manipulate[
 Plot[{g[x, k], gd[x, k], gdd[x, k]}, {x, -5, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Orange, Dashed}, {Green, Dashed}},
  Frame -> True, Epilog -> sol[k], PlotRange -> {-5, 10}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"g[x]= ", g[x, k]}],
  GridLines -> {Cases[sol[k], Point[{a_, b_}] :> a, All], None},
  PlotLegends -> 
   Column[{PointLegend[{Red, Green}, {"g''[x]>0", "g''[x]<0"}],
     LineLegend[{Blue, {Orange, Dashed}, {Green, Dashed}}, {"g[x]", 
       "g'[x]", "g''[x]"}]}]], {k, -4, 4}]
```

[image]